# batch - Ignore spaces while parsing a variable using for loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file

batch-file

I am a newbie to batch scripting. I was writing a script which gets a value from a registry key in windows. I am using a for loop

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('reg query HKLM\Software\CDupe\ZIB\  /v BackupSetLocation' ) do SET path_temp=%%B
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("%path_temp%") do SET BackupSet_Path=%%B
```

From this 2 for loops , I get the Value for the registry key `BackupSetLocation`.

The value I get when I `echo %BackupSet_Path%` is `C:\ProgramData\CDupe\CDupe Cloud Backup(x64)\zcb\conf`.

Problem is :

Now from the `BackupSet_Path` I want to extract only

`C:\ProgramData\CDupe\CDupe Cloud Backup(x64)\` .

I tried this

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('reg query HKLM\Software\CDupe\ZIB\ /v BackupSetLocation' ) do SET path_temp=%%B
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%A in ("%path_temp%") do SET BackupSet_Path=%%B
```

giving tokens = 1-4 , I get only `C:\ProgramData\CDupe\CDupe`

because there are whitespaces between "`CDupe Cloud Backup(x64)`".

Can anyone please tell me how to ignore those spaces and get this string

`C:\ProgramData\CDupe\CDupe Cloud Backup(x64)\`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html and "delims=\"?

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ('reg query HKLM\Software\CDupe\ZIB\ /v BackupSetLocation' ) do SET path_temp=%%B
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=\" %%A in ("%path_temp%") do SET BackupSet_Path=%%A\%%B\%%C\%%D\
```